# QGIS label text to raster

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, labeling

I created a multi-point shapefile and added number text to show as labels around the centroid of each point. Is is possible to rasterize the points and labels? I was thinking I could create a PDF and then georeference it back into QGIS?

[image]

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: I need them in a tif format to upload into another software package. I'd be more specific, but I am under a non-disclosure agreement. Sorry!

Comment: sounds like you need a WMS layer then

Comment: I'm not too familiar with WMS's, but will read into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rasterize the map using Project->Import/Export -> Export Map to Image. You can check "Append georeference information" and no need to georeference. You can select from several raster formats (tiff, jpg, png, etc). Dont't forget to copy the world file (jgw, pgw, etc) to keep georeference.

[image]